# How to replace entries diagonal in a grid

Tags: python, loops

After long hours trying to solve this puzzle without success I have to ask for help. So far I manage to built the grid using python but to insert a one character string diagonally its beyond my understanding of the language.

Please see my code below:

```
board = []
for x in range(0,5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

print(board)

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))

print_board(board)

O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
O O O O O
```

From here i tried to go line by line and pop the last of each row and insert interchangeably and x for example. However, I failed:

I need to get the follow as a result:

```
x O O O O
O x O O O
O O x O O
O O O x O
O O O O x
```

Comment: An ugly solution just for fun: `_ = [l.insert(i, 'x') or l.pop() for i, l in enumerate(board)]`. Or in a loop you can assign to list elements by index: `l[i] = 'x'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just

```
size = 5
board = []
for row in range(size):
    board.append(["O"]*row + ["X"] + ["O"]*(size-row-1))
```

Comment: tks also worked .. Could you tell me a bit more what this list comprehension is doing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are certain your board is a square, the diagonal elements will be where the row number and column number are the same. You can access each row by row = board[rowNum], and from there row[colNum] will give you a single element. If rowNum == colNum you're on a diagonal. You can squish the two together like I have done below (board[i][i]).

Note: If your board is a list (mutable object) calling it in a function like this will change the contents of the variable that was passed into boardObject even without returning "boardObject" so heads up on that one.

```
    def replace_diag(boardObject, replacement):
        for i in range(len(boardObject)):
             boardObject[i][i] = replacement
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to write x where `i == j`?

```
board = []
for x in range(0,5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

print(board)

def print_board(board):
  for row in board:
    print(" ".join(row))


for i in range (0, 5):
  for j in range(0, 5):
    if i == j:
      board[i][j] = 'x'

print(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a very convenient function for loops in Python called *enumerate*. It simply returns not only the element of an iterable but also its index - have a look:

```
def print_board(board):
  for i, row in enumerate(board):
    row[i] = 'x'
    print(" ".join(row))
```

Note that this changes your board 2D-array. If you don't want this, you can e.g. add a helper variable.

Answer (score 0):

board = []
for x in range(0,5):
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

print(board)

def print_board(board):
  for i,row in enumerate(board):
      row[i]="X"

print_board(board)